# Problems Allocating Objects of Derived Class Where Base Class has Abstract Virtual Functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I am trying to get this Zombie/Human agent based simulation running, but I am having problems with these derived classes (Human and Zombie) who have parent class "Creature". I have 3 virtual functions declared in "Creature" and all three of these are re-declared AND DEFINED in both "Human" and "Zombie". But for some reason when I have my program call "new" to allocate memory for objects of type Human or Zombie, it complains about the virtual functions being abstract. Here's the code:

header:

```
class Creature
{          
public:
      virtual void Attack(Grid G) =0;
      virtual void AttackCreature(Grid G, int attackdirection) =0;
      virtual void Breed(Grid G) =0;
      virtual ~Creature() {}          
      void Die();
      void Move(Grid G);
      int DecideSquare(Grid G);
      void MoveTo(Grid G, int dir);           
};

class Human : public Creature 
{
public:          
      void Attack(Grid G);
      void AttackCreature(Grid G, int attackdirection);
      void Breed(Grid G); //will breed after x steps and next to human          
      int DecideAttack(Grid G);
};

class Zombie : public Creature
{
   public:
      void Attack(Grid G); 
      void AttackCreature(Grid G, int attackdirection);
      void Breed(Grid G) {} //does nothing  
      int DecideAttack(Grid G);
};
```

cpp:

```
void Creature::Move(Grid G) {...}
int Creature::DecideSquare(Grid G) {...}
void Creature::MoveTo(Grid G, int dir) {...}
void Creature::Die() {...}
void Human::Breed(Grid G) {...}   
int Human::DecideAttack(Grid G) {...}
void Human::AttackCreature(Grid G, int attackdirection) {...}
int Zombie::DecideAttack(Grid G) {...}
void Zombie::AttackCreature(Grid G, int attackdirection) {...}
void Zombie::Attack(Grid G) {...}
```

Comment: Please remove all the irrelevant code. Do it by creating a testcase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a pure virtual function declared: `virtual void Creature::Attack(Grid G)` but there was no implementation for the derived class `Human`, i.e. there was no `void Human::Attack(Grid G)` method defined, which is why I was getting a `vtable` error. It couldn't find the source code for the function that I promised. Bad me!

Answer (score 3):

In `Creature`:

```
virtual void Breed() =0;
```

in `Human`:

```
void Breed(Grid G);
```

These are different functions; the latter does not override the former. Make the pure virtual function in `Creature` take the proper parameters.

This is also true for `Attack()`.

Comment: they're the other way around. ^^

Comment: Ok, I fixed what you found. I'm not 100% sure which code is irrelevant at this point, but I am still getting errors. Undefined reference to 'vtable for Human'

Comment: @user1743901: Now you need to declare and define virtual destructors.

Comment: Do you mean 1 virtual destructor for `Creature`? I don't use dynamic member variables so I thought the default destructors would be sufficient. I added `virtual ~Creature() =0;` in `Creature`, but what's the point of adding destructors to the derived classes if they aren't going to do anything? Also adding destructors did not solve the problem.

Comment: @user1743901: The default destructors are not `virtual`, which is where the problem lies. Do not make them _pure_ virtual, but properly `virtual` with a definition (even if that definition is empty). i.e. `virtual ~Creature() {}`

Comment: Alright, I took out the `=0` so now the destructor reads `virtual ~Creature() {}` but the problem persists. Do the destructors in the derived classes need to be explicitly declared?

Comment: Ok The problem was I did not have an implementation of `Human::Attack(Grid G)` even though I declared a virtual `Creature::Attack(Grid G)`